# QGridLayout не растягивается на всё окно в QMainWindow

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlayout, qmainwindow

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QFont, QFontDatabase, QIcon, QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class PageGeneral(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.page.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(120,120,30);")

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(
            self.page)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.label_content = QLabel(
            'Hello World', self, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_content.setStyleSheet("background-color: #064635")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_content, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        font = self.label_content.font()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_content.setFont(font)

        self.statusBar()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = PageGeneral()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Если я пробую добавить сетку для всего окна

```
        self.content = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.content.addWidget(self.page)
        self.content.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.content.setSpacing(0)
```

То при запуске пишет

```
QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to PageGeneral "", which already has a layout,
```

то есть `QLayout` на `QLayout` накладываю, я так понимаю. Тогда по какой причине не работает стандартный `QLayout` от `QMainWindow`?

Но если я делаю так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QFont, QFontDatabase, QIcon, QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class PageGeneral(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.page.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(120,120,30);")

        self.content = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.content.addWidget(self.page)
        self.content.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.content.setSpacing(0)

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(
            self.page)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.label_content = QLabel(
            'Hello World', self, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_content.setStyleSheet("background-color: #064635")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_content, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        font = self.label_content.font()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_content.setFont(font)

        # self.statusBar()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = PageGeneral()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

То сетка работает как надо и виджеты растягиваются на странице, но в этом случае нет метода `statusBar`, который мне нужен.

Для интереса создал болванку в *Qt Designer*, накинул `QGridLayout` и скомпоновал её по сетке.

При переводе в python-код мне выдало вот что:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

То есть говоря простым языком форматировщик создал `QGridLayout` и здесь он работает, потому что это создал форматировщик, а мной написанный `QGridLayout` не работает потому что потому. (WTF???).

Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> void QMainWindow::**setCentralWidget**(QWidget *widget)
>
> Устанавливает данный виджет как центральный виджет главного окна.
>
> Примечание: QMainWindow становится владельцем указателя виджета и удаляет его в соответствующее время.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class PageGeneral(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.page.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(120,120,30);")

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(
            self.page)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.label_content = QLabel(
            'Hello World', self, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_content.setStyleSheet("background-color: #064635")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_content, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        font = self.label_content.font()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_content.setFont(font)

        self.statusBar()
        
        self.setCentralWidget(self.page)                        # +++


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = PageGeneral()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень странная логика у PyQt5. Ведь centralwidget задаётся как  QtWidgets.QWidget. Видимо это определяет MainWindow в параметре. НУ и как всегда спасибо!

Comment: @PandaStock пожалуйста. Почитайте, будет полезно https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework